# Do Ferengi eat humanoids as insinuated in Encounter at Farpoint?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, ferengi

When leaving the administrator's office at Farpoint-station, Picard insinuates that the Ferengi "found their last associates tasty", indicating that they would eat other intelligent humanoids.

Has this ever been picked up again? Was Picard simply bluffing, in order to get better terms for the Federation?

Comment: Well, if Picard was a Mary Sue for Roddenberry, he would have easily believed that evil money-grabbing Ferengi eat humans and put the blood of christian ...err... Federation babies into their matza. *Picturing Pickard in a Che T-shrit*.

Comment: Bluffing - up to this point, the Federation hadn't actually (knowingly) had direct dealings with the Ferengi.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general the [Ferengi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ferengi) are mostly consumers of small insects:

> Traditional Ferengi cuisine consisted largely of slugs, insects, grubs, and other creatures Humans would call "bugs". Many partook in the beetle snuff habit, snorting a fine powder of dried beetles. In one instance, Jake Sisko told Nog that he was helping his girlfriend who was studying to become an entomologist, to which Nog replied "What's an entomologist?" Jake explained that it was "someone who studies bugs." Nog, misunderstanding the science, replied "Ohhh!, she wants to become a chef!" However, only native bugs were considered edible, and foreign (off-planet) bugs are treated with disdain. (DS9: "Sanctuary")

According to the Memory Alpha article on the [Encounter at Farpoint](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint#Apocrypha) under Apocrypha:

> When Groppler Zorn threatened to give access to Farpoint Station to the Ferengi Alliance, Picard remarked that he hopes the Ferengi find Zorn as tasty as they did their past associates. The novel The Buried Age establishes that the Ferengi's early reputation as a dangerous race was merely propaganda established by Zek because the Ferengi, after hearing early reports about the Federation and their moneyless economy, decided that the Federation might well be insane if they truly did not seek profit. Zek also threw funding into a large military buildup in order to preserve their appearance as a dangerous race and in order to defend themselves against the Federation, should it prove necessary.

This was probably done as the development of the Ferengi race portrayed them as decidedly not the kind of species that would eat sentient beings.

Comment: "Ohhh!, she wants to become a chef!" - that should be your camaign slogan :)

Answer (score 5):

There was never any evidence to show that Ferengi at humans or other sentients.

There are serveral points to support this from on-screen.  First, in several episodes of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, [The Jem'Heddar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Jem%27Hadar_%28episode%29) and in [*Little Green Men*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Little_Green_Men_%28episode%29), they mention that they have never had slavery or genocide and they feel this makes them morally superior to other races, indicating they do have ethics and pride in standing by them.

Ferengi are all about profit, and there's no profit in eating another sentient.  (At least until all his or her money has been obtained.)  It also creates a conflict and risk, since it would violate the laws of most other species and the Ferengi have been shown, over and over, to be risk adverse unless profit in proportion to the risk is involved.

I heard David Gerrold, who was involved in the creation and the first season of *Star Trek: The Next Generation* talk about the creation of the series and of the Ferengi.  He said they were very disappointed in how the Ferengi turned out.  If you want a glimpse at what they wanted for the Ferengi, look at [*The Last Outpost*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Last_Outpost_%28episode%29), where there's an attempt to make them look physically threatening.  The intent was to make them a small, quick and ferocious creature, very much like, as Gerrold said, bobcats.  They felt that did not work at all.

Allowing for lead time (it took over 6 weeks from script completion to finishing an episode), notice that they dropped that image of the Ferengi rather quickly.  (You see some of this in [*The Battle*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Stargazer).)

I don't know if the original intent was to have the Ferengi eat sentients, but it does fit with the intent to make them a small, quick, and ferocious race.  Once they finished *The Last Outpost*, however, and saw how they came across, they decided they were not a physical threat and that's when the focus on profit (even though mentioned before) became their defining point.  It was clear they could no longer use the Ferengi as a physically threatening species and had to go in another direction with them.

And, of course, it is very likely when Picard used that line, he intended it mainly to create a sense of discomfort as part of a bluff, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

DS9: The Ascent

When Quark and Odo crash land and are forced climb a mountain, they fall and Odo breaks his leg.

Quark makes a stretcher and Odo tells him not to be a hero and that he will get the transmitter to the top of the mountain faster by leaving him.  Quark declines and explains that he is taking Odo with to eat him in the event of his death.

Comment: considering the entire episode is basically a riff on the Odd Couple (also w/ Jake and Nogg's story) and considering the love/hate relationship Odo and Quark have - its highly likely this was Quark just screwing with Odo. It's certainly something to be taken with a grain of jumja

Comment: How does a shape-shifter "break his leg"? (Not questioning the answer, but the original writing!) Even it it was a problem, couldn't he just ooze a bit to make a splint?

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't seen the whole series, so I don't want to spoil anything if you (or anyone else reading this) wants to watch it for the first time. That being said, there is actually a legit explanation. Once you arrive at that episode, it will make sense.